# Java servlets получить страницу конкретного пользователя после авторизации

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet, filter, аутентификация

Не могу понять, каким образом получить страницу с данными конкретного пользователя после прохождения авторизации

Фильтр:

```
public class AuthenticationFilter implements Filter {
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

}

@Override
public void destroy() {

}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    String login = request.getParameter("login");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    UserDaoImpl userDao = new UserDaoImpl();

    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    if (nonNull(session) && nonNull(session.getAttribute("login")) && nonNull(session.getAttribute("password"))) {
        User.ROLE role = (User.ROLE) session.getAttribute("role");

        moveToMenu(request, response, role);
    } else if (userDao.userIsExist(login, password)) {

        User.ROLE role = userDao.getRoleByLoginPassword(login, password);

        request.getSession().setAttribute("password", password);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("login", login);
        request.getSession().setAttribute("role", role);

        moveToMenu(request, response, role);
    } else {
        moveToMenu(request, response, User.ROLE.UNKNOWN);
    }
}

private void moveToMenu(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res, User.ROLE role) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (role.equals(User.ROLE.ADMIN)) {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/adminPage.jsp").forward(req, res);
    } else if (role.equals(User.ROLE.USER)) {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/userPage.jsp").forward(req, res);
    } else {
        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/view/index.jsp").forward(req, res);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы храните данные о пользователе в качестве атрибутов сессии:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("password", password);
request.getSession().setAttribute("login", login);
request.getSession().setAttribute("role", role);
```

следовательно и получать их нужно **из атрибутов сессии**. Есть два способа это сделать: *JSP Scriptlets* и *JSP Expression Language*.

### 1. JSP Scriptlets

Здесь все понятно, так как мы просто вставляем *Java-код* в *HTML-страницу*. Страница будет выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
<html><body>
    <h1>Dear, User!</h1>
    <br />Your login: <% out.println(session.getAttribute("login")); %>
    <br />Your password: <% out.println(session.getAttribute("password")); %>
    <br />Your role: <% out.println(session.getAttribute("role")); %>
</html></body>
```

Выглядит ужасно. Нельзя просто написать?

`<% session.getAttribute("login") %>`

Нет, нельзя. Вернее можно :) Но логина на странице HTML Вы не увидите. Дело в том, что Ваша *.jsp* страница в итоге преобразовывается в сервлет. А как в сервлете отправить пользователю *HTML-страницу*?

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("...");
...
```

Очень не хочется писать что-то подобное:

```
out.println("<html><body>");
...
out.println("</html></body>");
```

Вы просто сойдете с ума писать *HTML-страницу* в `out.println()`. Для этого была придумана технология *JavaServer Pages*, а также для того, чтобы разделить представление (*HTML-страница*) от *Java-кода* (это называется *паттерн MVC*). Но все не так плохо, можно написать так:

```
<html><body>
    <h1>Dear, User!</h1>
    <br />Your login: <%= session.getAttribute("login") %>
    <br />Your password: <%= session.getAttribute("password") %>
    <br />Your role: <%= session.getAttribute("role") %>
</html></body>
```

Синтаксис <%= ... %> называется *JSP Expression*. Выражение внутри помещается в `out.print(...);`.

`<%= session.getAttribute("login") %> -> out.println(session.getAttribute("login"));` (это уже будет в сервлете)

### 2. JSP Expression Language

Здесь тоже существует несколько способов: `${sessionScope.attributeName}` и `{attributeName}`. **Нужно иметь ввиду**, что во втором способе Вы не указываете где искать данный атрибут. В таком случае атрибут будет искаться в следующем порядке: *pageScope*, *requestScope*, *sessionScope*, *applicationScope*. Будет найден первый атрибут с соответствующим именем.

```html
<html><body>
    <h1>Dear, User!</h1>
    <br />Your login: ${sessionScope.login}
    <br />Your password: ${sessionScope.password}
    <br />Your role: ${sessionScope.role}
</html></body>
```

Можно написать еще проще:

```html
<html><body>
    <h1>Dear, User!</h1>
    <br />Your login: ${login}
    <br />Your password: ${password}
    <br />Your role: ${role}
</html></body>
```

**Примечание:** в *JSP Scriptlets* я использовал *out* и *session* и ничего о них не упомянул. Это так называемые **JSP Implicit Objects** (неявные объекты). Как и почему их можно использовать на *JSP-странице*? Как я упоминал **JSP-страница в итоге становиться сервлетом**. В данном сервлете перед строками `out.println(...);` есть строки:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
...
```

[Здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_implicit_objects.htm) можете посмотреть список всех неявных объектов.

Собственно в *JSP Expression Language* *sessionScope* также является неявным объектом. Посмотреть весь список можно [здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm).

### Совет:

Почитайте книгу [Head First Servlets and JSP](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0596516681). Все эти моменты в ней очень подробно описаны.

**Update:** Я предлагаю следующую страницу:

```
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>
<html><body>
    <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${user == null}">
            <h1>Hello, guest!</h1>
        </c:when>

        <c:otherwise>
            <h1>Dear, User!</h1>
            <br />Your login: ${login}
            <br />Your password: ${password}
            <br />Your role: ${role}

            <form action="/change" method="POST">
                <br />Change your login: <input type="text" name="login" />
                <br />Change your password: <input type="password" name="password" />
                <br /><input type="submit" value="Change" />
            </form>
        <c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</html></body>
```

Вместо того, чтобы отдельно задавать *login*, *password* и *role* лучше создать класс User и уже объект данного класса "класть" в атрибут сессии:

```
...
User user = new User(login, password, role);
session.setAttribute("user", user);
...
```

Создаете сервлет, который обрабатывает *POST-запросы* с URL: `.../change` и изменяет данные пользователя в базе данных.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, я понял как пользоваться jsp. Прошу прощения, видимо вопрос сформулирован не корректно, мне нужно получить доступ к предположим редактированию данных юзера.

Comment: @SamKilanoff следовательно на странице пользователя Вам нужно не только отобразить данные пользователя, но и предоставить ему возможность их изменять. Для этой цели на страницу нужно добавить поля для ввода нового логина, пароля и т.д. Значения этих полей можно изначально задать первоначальными значениями.

Comment: @SamKilanoff я обновил ответ. В конце добавил свой вариант. Надеюсь будет полезным.

Comment: Да, то что нужно, спасибо большое!